# Crm 2015 plugin template

Tags: templates, plugins, sdk, dynamics-crm-2015

I installed the CRM 2015 sdk and VS2013 templates.  There is no plugin template.  Where is it now?  Can't find a way to find any information related to it.  Anyone has installed the sdk? Are there plugin creation template?

Answer (score 0):

To have templates of plugin you should:

1. Install CRM Developer Toolkit.
2. There is no CRM Developer Toolkit for VS 2013 so you will have to use following article to make it compatible - [http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tWaqYo_LhRQJ:www.hashtagcrm.com/%3Fp%3D79+&cd=1&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=th](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tWaqYo_LhRQJ:www.hashtagcrm.com/%3Fp%3D79%20&cd=1&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=th)

Comment: There is one at microsoft.  It installs just fine.  But there aré no plugin template.  I can see the Uli templates.  Also, i have a,ready done that on CRM 2011, but this time that trick is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to add the CRM 2013 templates to VS2013:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/tsgrdcrmblog/archive/2014/08/23/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-toolkit-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx